# How to cast an custom object to List<object>

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a parent class, with has a property that contain a list of the children class.

```
//Parent Class :

public class Family
{
    private MemberList _familymember = new MemberList();

    public MemberList FamilyMember
    {
        get { return _familymember ; }
        set { _familymember = value; }
    }

}

//Children Class :

public class Member
{
    private string _name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name= value; }
    }

}

public class MemberList : List<Member>
{

}


//And here is how I use them :

Family myFamily = new Family();
Member dad = new Member();
Member mom = new Member();

//I add the children into the parent property :

myFamily.FamilyMember.Add(dad);
myFamily.FamilyMember.Add(mom);


//I have other different similar parent-children classes, eg : School-Classroom, Country-States and etc.
//In one condition, I need to write a generic class to process the List<custom> type property :

//some function that will return a children list object.
object ChildrenList = somefunction();

List<object> ObjectList = (List<object>)ChildrenList;

//and trying to get the Type name inside the List :

Type ChildrenType = ObjectList.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];

//It gives me error :

Unable to cast object of type 'MemberList' to type'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]'

//or when I process other types of list

Unable to cast object of type 'ClassroomList' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]'

Unable to cast object of type 'StateList' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]'
```

I am trying to write a general class to process the list, therefore I wouldn't know the type of the list property. Any idea how I can cast them into List ?

All help is appreciated !!

**Update & Solution :**

Like aevitas suggested, I have changed the list property to use

```
private List<Member> _familymember = List<Member>();
```

And then I use the IList interface I found in other topic,

```
object returnedList = somefunction(); // some function that return a List of object.

IList myList = (IList)returnedList ;
```

Now the rest of the code works, I can loop through the IList like normal.

Thanks all!

Comment: There should never be a real need to inherit from `List<T>`. You can use LINQ here `<SomeIEnumerable>.ToList<T>();`...

Comment: Why does somefunction() return object?

Comment: Create a method in MemberList like ToObjects(). With in there, use Linq for the conversion like "return this.{select whatever properties you want to include or simple ignore select}.ToList<object>();"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never inherit `List<T>`, instead you should declare one instead:

```
public class Family
{
    private List<Member> _familymember = List<Member>();

    public List<Member> FamilyMember
    {
        get { return _familymember ; }
        set { _familymember = value; }
    }

}
```

On top of that, you should never be casting your types down to `object`, use a common type or interface instead as D.R. suggested.

If you want to stick to your guns, and you want to convert your `MemberList` object to a `List<Member>`, you could do it like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetList<T>(List<T> source)
{
    return source;
}
```

And call it like this:
`var list = GetList<Member>(memberList).ToList();`

That should at least solve your compiler errors, but it won't solve the design errors in this one.

Comment: Thanks! I have change the list property to use 
    private List<Member>  and it works!

Answer (score 2):

You could add a common interface for all children classes (Member, Classroom & State), otherwise there is absolutely no connection between `List<object>` and `List<MemberType>` as this would allow the following:

```
List<object> myList = (List<object>) memberTypeList;
myList.Add(5); // oops
```

Also: as unfortunate as it is, there is no type aliasing in C# like there is in C or C++. Still, deriving from a class looks like its a workaround but its semantically wrong and should not be used.

Comment: any idea how should I write the interface class to link List<object> with List<MemberType> ?

Comment: You would of course link `List<IMyInterface>` instead.